# Failed to connect when device is disconnected from PC

Tags: android, http, okhttp

I have an Android app which fetches data from the server using okhttp library. It's versioned here: https://github.com/ertrzyiks/android-http-data-widget

```
class LoadData() : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String? {
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        val url = URL("https://example.com/some/path")

        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .get()
            .build()

        try {
            val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
            val responseBody = response.body!!.string()

            return responseBody
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            return e.message
        }
    }
}
```

I also added the internet permission to my manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I connect the mobile device to my computer with USB cable, run application on that device using Android Studio and everything works properly. The request is issued and I can see the response.

When I disconnect USB cable though I see the following error:

```
failed to connect to example.com/ip here (port 443) from /192.168.1.10 (port 41446) after 10000ms
```

The issue occurs also when I use HttpUrlConnection.

My mobile device is Samsung Galaxy S8, the Android version is 9.

When I issue a request and then plug USB cable, it works. So apparently my app can access internet only when the device is connected to ADB. How can I fix this?

The libraries I use:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Samsung device was put in a battery saving mode with **Restrict background data** option checked. This option prevents background apps from using Wi-Fi and mobile data. Once I disabled this option, my widget has access to the internet connection even without a connected debugger.

How to disable this option:

1. Go to Settings
2. Device care
3. Click Battery icon
4. Power mode
5. Currently selected power mode (I had *Medium power saving*)
6. Uncheck *Restrict background data*
7. Click Apply button